# Change Audio Output via Speaker Symbol

Tags: unity, pulseaudio, system-tray, output

Is there a way to change the Audio Output (and for the sake of completeness the Audio Input) conveniently via the Speaker Symbol of the Top-Bar of Ubuntu?

Just like I can change between Wifi networks, VPN connections etc. via the Network Symbol right next to the Speaker Symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity, there is no completely fast way but down at the bottom of the system tray icon menu you can click on "Sound Settings" and change it from there.

If you are using KDE, you can click on the speaker and select to open the full KMixer window, and change it from there.

Can't help you with other DEs.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, I know. That is the fasted way, I've done this for years now. Is there a place where I can put up a feature request to the Ubuntu development team?

Comment: @SvenR.Kunze I don't know for sure.